# Client validation not working on the shared host but works when debugging

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-validation

I had the following property in model class:

```
[MaxLength(9), Required, DisplayName("Social security number")]
[RegularExpression(@"\d{3}-\d\d-\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid social security number")]
public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
```

Markup (Razor):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SocialSecurityNumber, new { id = "ssn" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SocialSecurityNumber)
```

The generated HTML code is:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Invalid social security number" data-val-regex-pattern="\d{3}-\d\d-\d{4}" data-val-required="The Social security number field is required." id="ssn" name="SocialSecurityNumber" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SocialSecurityNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

However, there is no error message if I only type one number and click another input box on the published shared host site. The error message `Invalid social security number` will be displayed when debugging using Visual studio 2012 (chrome browser). What could cause the issue?

**Update:**
The html code generated on my local PC (Visual studio debugging) is.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Invalid social security number" data-val-regex-pattern="\d{3}-\d\d-\d{4}" data-val-required="The Social security number field is required." id="ssn" name="SocialSecurityNumber" type="text" value="" class="input-validation-error">
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="SocialSecurityNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="ssn" class="" style="">Invalid social security number</span></span>
```

It seems the html code of my local PC has `class="input-validation-error"`, which doesn't exist on the host site?